# Core dumped segmentation fault - access not within mapped region at address 0x0

Tags: c, pointers

so I'm getting a weird error when trying to run my program (the functions you see there, as well as Node and LinkedList are in a separate file and work correctly. Apparently there is some pointer here that's running amock, and I would really appreciate some help with fixing my core dump fault!!

Here's the code in the file I've written:

```
void insertion_sort(LinkedList *list, int (*compare)(void *, void *)) {

LinkedList *sorted; 
sorted = initialise_linked_list();

append_linked_list(sorted, list->head->data);
remove_head_linked_list(list);

while(list->tail != NULL){

    Node *b;
    b = initialise_node();
    sorted->head = b;   

    while(b){

        int num;
        num = strcmp(list->head->data, b->data); 
        if(num < 0){

            prepend_linked_list(sorted, list->head->data);
            remove_head_linked_list(list);
        }

        b = b->next;
    
    }
    
    if(!b){

    append_linked_list(sorted, list->head->data);
    remove_head_linked_list(list);

    }

}

free_linked_list(list);
print_linked_list(sorted, print_string);
```

}

Comment: Have you run your program in a debugger?  It'd probably stop right on the line with the problem.

Comment: I used valgrind and it just gave "compare_string" and "insertion_sort" - no line numbers etc

Comment: Compile with debug info: `-g3 -Og`

Comment: @JCWasmx86 I do not know how to do that sorry - I'm really new to C (and linux for that matter)

Comment: Then that is your next task, before writing any more code.  There should be lots of tutorials, etc, available.

Comment: The error you're seeing most likely means that you are dereferencing a NULL pointer somewhere.  It's by no means a "weird" message - get used to it if you are going to program in C.

Comment: Anyway, in order to get help with this, you should create a [mcve].  Code that calls lots of functions we can't see is not very helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: You work with lists : what is the contents of list->head when list->tail is NULL (exit of loop). In case of list it usually list is empty and so have no head, so head is probably also NULL.

Comment: You have a compare function(pointer) and you don't even use it. Why?

Comment: regarding: `if(!b){`  at this point in the code, the variable `b` will always contain NULL